# How are WordPress Post Relationships Created in the Database?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the [advanced custom fields plugin](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/relationship/) to create relationships between custom post types. My custom post types are course and institution. So when I add a course post via the admin dashboard, I select an institution related to the course.

However now I am inserting posts programmatically via a wpdb object, and I want to create the same relationships. Therefore I need to know how the ACF plugin is creating relationships.

At the moment I think I should just insert extra data as post-meta for the course. But is this all that is needed? Do I not need to also update the institution to have the course?

Comment: I'm adding the data from outside of wordpress, by instantiating a wpdb object, so I don't think I have access to wp_insert_post..what would the benefit be ?

Comment: Oh, I moved to an Answer. Well, this is an important piece of information, can you update the Question with this "outside of wp" thing?

Comment: Anyway, if you have access to `$wpdb`, you have all the rest too. I've just tested and `update_field` is available with `<?php define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );require( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/wp-load.php' );`

Answer (score 3):

It's better to use WP and the plugin's API for that. Doing it with `$wpdb` is not a good idea, because other plugins may hook into `wp_insert_post` and if we use `$wpdb` it completely bypasses that. If we [study the function](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/post.php#L2628), we can see that there's a lot going on there, not only a `wpdb->insert`.

ACF has its own logic to store meta data, simply using WP's [`update_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) is not enough.
After doing a [`wp_insert_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post), use the returned ID to do an [`update_field()`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/update_field/).

My point is: *we don't need to know* **"How are WordPress Post Relationships Created in the Database?"**. We use the functions provided by the platform and we have a code that's *future proof*.